# How can I find the coefficients of this logarithmic expression?

Tags: equation-solving

Knowing that $\log_{30}3=a$ and $\log_{30}5=b$, I would like to find $\log_{30}1350 = m$ in term $a$ and $b$.  I tried

```
Clear[a, b]
a = Log[30, 3];
b = Log[30, 5];
SolveAlways[Log[30, 1350] == m a + n b  + p, {m, n, p}]
```

I can't get the values of $m$, $n$, $p$.  How can I find the values of $m$, $n$, $p$?

Comment: Please edit your question, which has $\log_{303} = a$ but no corresponding code.  Also, please create a title that describes the content of your question to help in future searches.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Hi; The simplest one I can find is Log[30, 1350] == 2 Log[30, 3] + Log[30, 5] + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do it.

```
1350/30
FactorInteger[%]

(*
45
{{3, 2}, {5, 1}}
*)
```

Therefore $m=1+2a+b$.

You can also do:

```
Solve[(30^x) ( 3^y) ( 5^z) == 1350 && {x, y, z} >= 0, Integers]

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 1}} *)
```

yields the same solution.

Or again:

```
a := Log[30, 3]; b := Log[30, 5]; m := Log[30, 1350];
Solve[m == x + a y + b z && {x, y, z} >= 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 1}} *)
```

**Generalization**. Of course this will also work if you replace $1350$ by another integer as long as it can be written as $30^x\times3^y\times5^z$.

Comment: If x, y, z are reals number. How can I use your way?

Comment: @toandhsp If you allow $x,y,z$ to be real then a trivial solution is $m=\log_{30}1350 + 0\,a + 0\,b$.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
Clear[a, b, m, n, p]
a = Log[30, 3];
b = Log[30, 5];
eqn = Log[30, 1350] == m*a + n*b + p;

fi = FindInstance[
    eqn && Element[{m, n, p}, Integers] &&
     0 < n && 0 < m && 0 < p,
    {m, n, p}][[1]]

(*  {m -> 2, n -> 1, p -> 1}  *)

eqn /. fi // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```